# How to use C++ enum in Qt .js file?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I need to create a file with several shared functions for multiple QML files.

I tried to create a .js file, but seems like C++ enums don't work here. `FileSystemModel.TYPE_DIR` is undefined here, while in QML it works fine after `import FileSystemModel 1.0`

```
.pragma library

.import FileSystemModel 1.0 as FileSystemModel

function fsItemTypeToImage(type) {
    console.log(FileSystemModel.TYPE_DIR)
    switch (type) {
    case FileSystemModel.TYPE_DIR:
        return "/img/dir.png"
    case FileSystemModel.TYPE_FILE:
        return "/img/file.png" 
    }
    return null
}
```

FileSystemModel.h:

```
class FileSystemModel : public QAbstractListModel {
    Q_OBJECT 
public:
    enum Roles { NameRole = Qt::UserRole + 1, SizeRole, DateRole, TypeRole };

    enum ItemType {
        TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0,
        TYPE_FILE,
        TYPE_DIR, 
    };
    Q_ENUM(ItemType)
```

registration in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<FileSystemModel>("FileSystemModel", 1, 0, "FileSystemModel");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `qmlRegisterType<FileSystemModel>("FileSystemModel", 1, 0, "FileSystemModel")` you're registering a `FileSystemModel` QML module that contains a `FileSystemModel` type, so in your js when you write `.import FileSystemModel 1.0 as FileSystemModel` you're not actually importing your type but the QML module, that's why it's not working.

In your js file try changing `FileSystemModel.TYPE_DIR` to `FileSystemModel.FileSystemModel.TYPE_DIR`, that should do the trick.